# What's the difference between motivational letter and a cover letter?

Tags: phd, thesis, education

I am applying to different PhD positions (biological science) and some of the applications ask for motivational letter and others ask for a cover letter. I am bit confused because I always thought that they are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is none. The term "motivational letter" emphasizes the idea that you should motivate your application in that letter, but this idea applies to a "cover letter" as well.

Comment: Okay. Thank you !